# Copy/Paste does not work using Webview in Chrome Packaged Apps on OS X

Tags: macos, copy-paste, google-chrome-app

In Mac OSX copy/paste does not work in a Chrome Packaged App.

I installed my app on both Windows XP Chrome and a Chrome OS.  I'm able to copy/paste in both the Windows and Chrome OS environment but not Mac OS X using the same exact app.

Chrome version: 27.0.1453.47  Channel: beta
OS Version: OS X 10.7.5

I posted this as [Issue 230148](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230148) on  Chromium Issues.

The app code is hosted on github: https://github.com/damondouglas/chrome_drive_realtime_quickstart

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Added some comments to the bug. If I could add a "webview" tag of some kind to this question, I would.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight!  I still wonder why though it works in chrome os and windows xp but not mac osx.  I tried both command-C and control-C.  Thank you, again, for your time and help.

Comment: We're working on it! Thanks for the report! Fady

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with today's Chrome Canary and my own developed packaged app. I'm running OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Thank you. Was your packaged app utilizing the webview? I tried also on Chrome Canary with no success.